# Extra Single Quote - Can't Get Rid of It

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the following code (using JavaScript/jQuery) I'm controlling a slideshow/preview slider type widget on my site. It works just fine. We have small indicator boxes which highlight which of the available slides you're in. They work too. but for some reason, a single quote shows up between each one of them. I was able to trace it down to the line I've commented on below in caps. The very last SINGLE quote you see seems to be causing it, but when I remove it, it breaks the code. Why could this single quote be required? I can't tell what it's matching up with.

```
for(var i = -1; i < numberOfSlides; i++)
    {
        $('#locationBar').append("<span class='locator' id='locator_" + i + "'><a></a></span>'");
//THE LAST SINGLE QUOTE HERE IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE QUOTES BETWEEN THE SLIDE INDICATORS. GETTING RID OF IT BREAKS IT THOUGH. INVESTIGATE.
        if(i < 0)
        {
            $('#locator_' + i).css('visibility','hidden');
            continue;
        }
        $('#locator_' + i).bind('click',function(){window.location=$('#link_' + currentPosition).attr('href');});
        $('#locator_' + i).hover(function(){

            var newPosition = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < numberOfSlides; j++)
            {
                if($(this).attr('id') == "locator_" + j)
                {
                    newPosition = j;
                }
            }
            if(currentPosition==newPosition)
                return;

            jump(currentPosition,newPosition);


            currentPosition=newPosition;

            clearTimeout(delayTimer);
            delayScroll();
        });
    }
```

Comment: `.append("<span class='locator' id='locator_" + i + "'><a></a></span>'");` should be `.append("<span class='locator' id='locator_" + i + "'><a></a></span>");` If that "breaks" it, define what break means. Consider setting up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Removing it doesn't break the code for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ySGCb/ Your issue may be elsewhere?

Comment: @rar: Is your text editor or ide messing up the syntax highlighting when you remove that single quote?

Comment: I'll have to look elsewhere in the code then...seems odd though.

Comment: @jlaceda I've tried to check that it doesn't seem to change the highlighting in any unusual way.

Comment: If you can set up a jsfiddle we can help you...

Comment: Are you appending or removing content of `#locationBar` somewhere outside of this code-snippet? There you might find a pair for this ghost-apostrophe.

Comment: @user1090190 "am not i am" set up a jsfiddle above, so unless I include the entire site (PHP and all) it'll be the same.

Comment: @Teemu no the code you see is what creates location bar, the only thing changing content is styles (which wouldn't add apostrophes).

Comment: @rar I meant with all of your JS silly, obviously the snippet you posted should be fine

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Mixing single- and doublequotes within a same sentence may cause problems.

```
$('#locationBar').append('<span class="locator" id="locator_' + i + '"><a></a></span>');
```

Though user1277499's answer supposed to tackle this problem too, and it's not working?

Comment: There has to be another reason for that. The last `'` is pairless. You could write whatever after it before the last `"`, without breaking the code.

Comment: Yes, I know. Point is that you're telling OP to do exactly what is currently being done.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the string.

It makes sense that you get extra quotes.
The end of your line is

```
"'><a></a></span>'"
```

So you get the quotes within the double quotes.
escaped example :

```js
 $('#locationBar').append('<span class=\'locator\' id=\'locator_' + i + '\'><a></a></span>');
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work either. I'll have to dig through the entire document to find out where this strange pairing is occurring.

Comment: I typed it in incorrectly. the correct code is : $('#locationBar').append('<span class=\'locator\' id=\'locator_' + i + '\'><a></a></span>'); : I tested this just now and my old version did not work. Sorry for not testing my answer, but this new line does work. I added an escaped quote after locator_. That was the flaw.